# Writing a loop to slice a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, slice

I have a pretty basic loop question:

I have a matrix (365x20). So for twenty years I have daily rainfall data.

I need to slice the matrix in order to conduct the next steps of my analysis, which I did like this:

```
year1 <- as.vector(Rainfall_data$year1)                   
year2 <- as.vector(Rainfall_data$year2)             
...         
year20 <- as.vector(Rainfall_data$year20)
```

This gives me in total 20 single 1x365 vectors.

Now, I want to do the same for the transposed Rainfall data to obtain a vector containing the value of the same day for all twenty years. Since  this would mean to do

```
as.vector(t_Rainfall_data$day1-365)
```

I wanted to write a loop. The columns are called day1 to day 365. `t_Rainfall_data` would be the transposed matrix. Main aim is to obtain in total 365 single 1x20 vectors.

I tried several ways, but failed them all.

Comment: You don't need to transpose what seems to be a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. Try `lapply(seq_len(nrow(Rainfall_data)), function(i) Rainfall_data[i, ])`. This will produce a `list` of vectors.

Comment: You don't need to slice the data out of a data frame to do the next step of your analysis. Tell us what the next step is and we'll show you how to do it easily without copy/paste/editing your code. It's easy to loop over rows/columns of a data frame or matrix. It's hard to loop over individual objects in your environment.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you feel you need to take a perfectly useful data frame and chop it up into that many isolated objects?

Comment: Keep it as is is probably a better idea. Check out [hydroTSM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydroTSM/) and [openair](http://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/) packages. They have many useful functions for time series data

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right: anything you want to do with the vector `day1` can just as well be done with `t_Rainfall_data$day1` (or likely with `Rainfall_data[1,]`) and it's better practice to slice your dataframe when you're doing something with it rather than creating a lot of redundant vectors out of it. Similarly, even if you need a bunch of objects, it's almost always easier to deal with a list of objects than it is to create separate named objects. All that said, here's how to get what you're asking for:

As in comments, you can return a list of vectors with

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(Rainfall_data)), function(i) Rainfall_data[i, ])
```

If you would prefer a loop, and to create the objects rather than return a list, you can do something like

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Rainfall_data){
  assign(paste0("day",i),as.vector(t_Rainfall_data[,paste0("day",i)]))
  }
```

`assign` will create an object named after the string passed to it, that contains the second argument.

Comment: Don't encourage OP to make bad choices.

Comment: I'm rather explicitly not encouraging it with the final paragraph there, but feel like it's worth answering the question asked rather than only criticizing bad style. Even though it's probably the wrong way, I don't think I'm in a position to say there's absolutely no use-case where creating a bunch of vectors out of a dataframe isn't the best solution (e.g. you're dealing with someone else's poorly written code which expects a bunch of named objects, and you don't have time to rewrite it). In the name of encouraging good choices I'll reverse the structure to put the admonition first.

Comment: If you insist on answering, I'd suggest demonstrating a simple loop over rows of matrix (even without the body filled in) and compare it to a loop using `paste` and `get` to show how this complicates the next step. Personally, I'd also prefer `split(Rainfall_data, seq_len(nrow(Rainfall_data)))` to the `lapply`.